# Database output

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I uploaded data to dbase and it's looking good in the dbase like:

> MAJORPLUS CREATION
>  0023055169
>  Diamond Bank Nigeria Plc N26,690.00
>  Tracking: 219517
>  |
>
> ENOCH KURE
>  0020477292
>  Diamond Bank Nigeria Plc
>   N12,560.00
>  Tracking: 219675
>  |

but the out looks clustered like this:

```
MAJORPLUS CREATION 0023055169 Diamond Bank Nigeria Plc N26,690.00 Tracking: 219517 |   ENOCH KURE 0020477292 Diamond Bank Nigeria Plc N12,560.00 Tracking: 219675 |
```

Please I do I make it show like the original input?

Comment: So what's the difference? I can't find any differences in the data expect for formatting.

Comment: you want that in separate lines ?

Answer (score 0):

You can output your data:

- in `<pre>` tags which will keep new lines
- or (assuming that you are using PHP) u will need to output your data through function `nl2br` which will convert your new lines to `<br>` tags and create HTML break lines.